# My JMeter script stops execution after while loop

Tags: jmeter

My jmeter script stops execution after while loop is executed and further operations are aborted and script is halted.
I am using ${lineNo} as condition for while, ${lineNo} is the name of first column in .csv file.

Comment: You might want to give a little more detail; you'll get better answers that way. Eg. Stops how? With errors or just does not continue. And did you look in the log, this will tell you more about what exactly is happening.

Comment: hi @OliverLloyd thanks for reply, i observed the log file
and following is the content after 1st while loop:
2012/04/18 11:52:20 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file detected 
After this I have one more while loop, which is not executed after the first while loop, what should I do? I want to execute all the operations in my test plan.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have stop threads on EOF set to true in your CSV Config, change it to false.

Comment: When I did that, my while loop gone into infinite loop
following are the set attributes of  while and csv config:
while: "${lineNo}" != "<EOF>"
csv: Allow quoted data= false; Recycle on Eof=false; Stop thread on EOF= false;

Comment: So then logically, if the loop never ends, the value of ${lineNo} is never equal to "<EOF>". Why don't you use a debug sampler to trace the value of this var and set the while statement accordingly.

Comment: hi @oliver I used debug sampler and analyse the value of ${lineNo} it becomes EOF.

Comment: EOF or <EOF>? The statement while: "${lineNo}" != "<EOF>" is pretty classic stuff, either there's a type mismatch of this var does not end up as "<EOF>". Or, it isn't actually running infinately and there are just more entries in the file than you thought.

Comment: There are many variables in .csv:                                                            lineNo,name,age                                                     and I am giving while condition as "${lineNo}" != "<EOF>"

Comment: The while loop stops but it iterates for 1 more time , i mean to say it iterate for first <EOF> and then it stops.